# How to parse subchild multiple node in a single child node in XML using Xpath in Php

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xpath

friend, I'm unable to print the sub child from the child node in the give XML below, Kindly help me to fix this problem.

XML :

```
<section index="2.2.4" title="Recommendation" ref="RECOMMENDATION">
          <text>DWS strongly recommends that all authentication credentials should be configured with a strong password.</text>
          <text>DWS recommends that:</text>
          <list type="bullet">
            <listitem>passwords should be at least eight characters in length;</listitem>
            <listitem>characters in the password should not be repeated more than five times;</listitem>
            <listitem>passwords should include both upper case and lower case characters;</listitem>
            <listitem>passwords should include numbers;</listitem>
            <listitem>passwords should include punctuation characters;</listitem>
            <listitem>passwords should not include the username;</listitem>
            <listitem>passwords should not include a device's name, make or model;</listitem>
            <listitem>passwords should not be based on dictionary words.</listitem>
          </list>
          <text>Notes for Cisco Catalyst Switch devices:</text>
          <text>The following commands can be used on Cisco Catalyst Switch devices to set the enable password, create a local user with a password and to delete a local user:<code><command>enable secret <cmduser>password</cmduser></command>
<command>username <cmduser>user</cmduser> secret <cmduser>password</cmduser></command>
<command>no username <cmduser>user</cmduser></command>
</code></text>
        </section>
```

CODE:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("toshibaconfig2.xml");

$report = $xml->xpath("//section [@index = '2.2.4'] //code");

//foreach ($report as $reports)

print_r($report);
```

I need to parse the `<code></code>` out in this order:

```
enable secret password
username user secret password
no username user
```

Kindly help me to fix this problem.

Comment: almost there, just target the `command`, then just use `asXML()` to get the whole text. like so: https://3v4l.org/YFIYj

Comment: Awesome @Ghost Thanks a Lot, You are great Man.